Issue with black screen in monitor
I  have a dvi to dvi cable that goes from my monitor into my USB-C docking station, then I use a usb c to usb c cable to connect the docking station into my laptop.
My laptop has two graphic cards : One that is an Nvidia one and the other one is an Intel one. In order to bypass  the intel graphics card while playing I use the "Only display second monitor" while playing in order to utilize my second screen, and max out on the Nvidia without utilizing the intel one.
Now  I have a refresh rate of 239.6 hz which feels like it is the case when using this usb c to usb c cable. The issue is that I get black screens from time to time that cut audio and image for a few seconds. This can vary from 5 times in an hour to twice a day.
I thought the issue was with the usb c to usb c cable so I bought a new one supporting until 4K 60 fps but it keeps making my whole screen black and only works when I set the refresh the rate to 60 fps, and then also only for a few seconds... What can I do in order to not have black screens anymore ?
Is there a cable suggestion I don't know about ? Or is there a "bypass" that I don't know that makes the dpi to dpi the main transfer of image tool?

I am not sure what you are asking here. What is a "dpi to dpi cable"? Do you perhaps mean "DVI"? If so, please correct this using the EDIT button. Also, while you're editing the post could you check for other spelling issues. Finally, try to apply some formatting, such as using paragraphs to break this apart into logical sections. Next, what are your computer's specs and details?
